# how to delete row, which is inserted within one minute from previously inserted row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of products view report. Each click on the product page is added in this table with data of user IP and DateTime.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `oc_product_viewed_report` (
  `viewed_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_ip` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`viewed_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Sample Data:

```
+-----------+------------+----------+---------+---------------------+
| viewed_id | product_id | store_id | user_ip | datetime            |
+-----------+------------+----------+---------+---------------------+
|        10 |      10051 |        5 | ::1     | 2018-06-24 15:15:57 |
|        11 |       9594 |       16 | ::1     | 2018-06-24 15:16:29 |
|        12 |       9596 |        5 | ::1     | 2018-06-24 15:16:33 |
|        13 |       9594 |       16 | ::1     | 2018-06-24 15:16:35 |
|        14 |       9594 |       16 | ::1     | 2018-06-24 15:16:37 |
|        15 |       9594 |       16 | ::1     | 2018-06-24 15:16:58 |
|        16 |       9596 |        5 | ::1     | 2018-06-24 15:16:59 |
|        17 |       9594 |       16 | ::1     | 2018-06-24 15:17:05 |
|        18 |       9918 |       16 | ::1     | 2018-06-24 15:17:07 |
|        19 |      10047 |        5 | ::1     | 2018-06-24 16:47:36 |
|        20 |      10047 |        5 | ::1     | 2018-06-24 16:48:04 |
+-----------+------------+----------+---------+---------------------+
```

Now I want to delete spam clicks data. So for that, how to delete a row, which was immediately inserted within 1 minute after previously inserted row datetime per products.

Is it possible? if yes then help me please,

Thank you

Comment: You would need to use a trigger for this operation.

Comment: I tend to agree with Gordon on this one: prevent such entries from being inserted into the table in the first place. You can use triggers or even calculated column + unique index to prevent fake views from being inserted into the table.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
Delete from oc_product_viewed_report R1
where exists 
(select id from  oc_product_viewed_report R2 where R2.datetime between R1.datetime and  DATE_ADD (R1.datetime ,INTERVAL +1 MINUTE  and R1.id > R2.id )
```

Comment: @jaypadaliya it would be really helpful, if you specified exactly what syntax error you received when you tried to run the above query. This way your feedback is pretty useless.

Comment: @kiran: exists operator does not need `id>`, since it checks whether the subquery returns any records.

Comment: @kirangadhe `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'R1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT `viewed_id` FROM oc_product_viewed_report R2 where R2.da' at line 1`

Comment: @kirangadhe Thank you for answer, this is sample data, you can test it
[link](https://nofile.io/f/Jz98qPNpwD4)